# Is there a way to transpose output of table as column headers?

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I have a table **candidate**

```
id          candidate_name
---------------------------
1            john
2            mary
```

and another table **units**

```
id name
--------
1  unit1
2  unit2
3  unit3
```

i would like to generate an output as

```
id  candidate_name  unit1  unit2  unit3
---------------------------------------
1       john        null   null  null
2       mary        null   null  null
```

Any way I can achieve this?

Comment: If you want to create a table as above, then you could dynamically build a create table script, but you shouldn't. This is not a good way to store data. If you mean just generate output in that format, then you *can* do this with a [dynamic pivot query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+server+dynamic+pivot) (there are thousands of examples available, and should only require a minor tweak for your needs with two tables). It is worth noting though that this is really a job for your presentation layer and not for SQL.

Comment: That helps a lot @GarethD. I only require to output it and not build a table. Could you also look into the follow-up to this which I have raised on dba.stackexchange https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/320947/is-there-a-way-i-can-dynamically-pivot-and-assign-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your data

```
CREATE TABLE candidate(
   id             int NOT NULL 
  ,candidate_name VARCHAR(40)
);
INSERT INTO candidate
(id,candidate_name) VALUES 
(1,'john'),
(2,'mary');

CREATE TABLE units(
   id   int NOT NULL 
  ,name VARCHAR(50)
);
INSERT INTO units
(id,name) VALUES 
(1,'unit1'),
(2,'unit2'),
(3,'unit3');
```

you should use `Cross Join` and `Pivot`

```
select 
  * 
from 
  (
    select 
      c.id, 
      candidate_name, 
      cast(null as int) id1, 
      name 
    from 
      candidate c 
      CROSS JOIN units u
  ) src pivot (
    max(id1) for name in ([unit1], [unit2], [unit3])
  ) piv;
```

using `Dynamic Sql`

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @names nvarchar(1000)= (
SELECT STRING_AGG(concat('[',name,']'),',') 
WITHIN GROUP  (order by id) from units)

set @SQL='select 
  * 
from 
  (
    select 
      c.id, 
      candidate_name, 
      cast(null as int) id1, 
      name 
    from 
      candidate c 
      CROSS JOIN units u
  ) src pivot (
    max(id1) for name in ('+ @names +' )
  ) piv;'

exec(@SQL)
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vujuVnxY)

Comment: Thanks @RF1991. I would like the list of units to be dynamic depending upon the units in units table